Raising python exception from native thread
I have a C++ class Runner that encapsulates running a native thread. This class is exposed to Python via pybind11, so start_thread is called from Python.
class Runner {
public:
    void start_thread() {
        thread_ = std::jthread([]{
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // do something
                }
            } catch (...) {
                pybind11::gil_scoped_acquire gil;
                pybind11::set_error(PyExc_RuntimeError, "Something horrible happend");
            }
        });
    }

private:
    std::jthread thread_;
};

Exception might be thrown in native thread, is there a way to reraise an exception from a native thread to Python?
I was thinking about using pybind11::set_error, but is it the right way? And if so what are the guarantees on when Python realises that there is an exception? If exceptions are checked as soon as Gil is released by a native thread - then this solution should be fine.

What are you hoping will happen with this exception? Do you want to catch it somewhere? Trying to handle an exception from one thread in another thread would already take a lot of manual work even if both threads were Python threads.

Alternative to exception would be a std::terminate, I'd hope that reraising exception in Python will allow Python interpreter to gracefully shutdown, calling potential finally blocks. Or if it's non terminal exception, Python could recover from that and restart native thread.

A more "c++ native" way is to throw the exception in c++ and register a pybind11 custom exception translator so pybind11 will translate it to a python exception

Note pybind11 has a net that translates all "unknown" exceptions to RuntimeError, you don't need to add one.

@AhmedAEK exception can't be raised from a native thread without violating GIL. More precisely - throwing exception in a native thread causes std::terminate because it's handled by C++ runtime, rather than Python

Okay, now i get it, you are using a jthread, the proper way now is to catch the exception with an exception_ptr then throw it in the destructor, make sure the destructor is marked noexcept(false) because destructors are noexcept by default, if you don't want a throwing destructor you can add a throwing join function and be sure to call that if you don't want to discard the exception

Also consider using packaged_task<void()> so you get functions like wait_for and automatic exception transportation, you don't even have to write the try, it is the c++ idiomatic way to create tasks and report errors

Like you noticed, you cannot let C++ exception escape jthread, because it will be handled on C++ side and cause crash. Relatively good way would be to store std::exception_ptr inside your Runner and provide additional interface to rethrow it in the caller side:
class Runner {
public:
  void start_thread() {
    thread_ = std::jthread([this] {
      try {
        throwSomething();
      } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        ePtr_ = std::current_exception();
      }
    });
  }
  void rethrow_if_needed() const {
    if (ePtr_) {
      std::rethrow_exception(ePtr_);
    }
  }

private:
  void throwSomething() { throw std::runtime_error("crit failure"); }
  std::jthread thread_;
  std::exception_ptr ePtr_;
};

Then your python code could look like:
runner = Runner()
runner.start_thread()

try:
    time.sleep(1)
    runner.rethrow_if_needed()
except Exception as e:
    print("caught: ", e)

std::runtime_error should be automatically translated to pythonic RuntimeError.
